# Функия некорректно изменяет значения поля в классе

Tags: typescript, devexpress, angular5

Я только начал работать Angular 5 (по сути даже заголовок вопроса не могу сделать корректно :-) ....).

Я пытаюсь добавить в `dx-data-grid` кнопку (с помощью `onToolbarPreparing(e)`) , которая покажет `dx-popup`. Его покажет в зависимости от значения `csvImportPopupVisible`, которое меняеться в функции `showCSVImportPopUp()`.

Но вот эта функция, по непонятным **для меня** причинам, не меняет это значения.
Это можно увидеть добавив `<div>{{csvImportPopupVisible}}</div>` (будет false), при этом, если в саму функцию `showCSVImportPopUp()` добавить алерт `alert(this.csvImportPopupVisible)` --> покажет true.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать, а то ну совсем не гуглиться у меня!

1) **state.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';


import CustomStore from "devextreme/data/custom_store";

import { StateModel } from '../../models/StateModel';
import { StateService } from '../../services/state.service';
import { UpdateItemModel } from '../../models/UpdateItemModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'administration-states',
    templateUrl: './state.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [StateService],
})
export class AdministrationStateComponent {
    statesDataSourse: any;
    csvMappingTemplate: string;
    csvImportPopupVisible = false;


    constructor(private stateService: StateService) {
        this.statesDataSourse = new CustomStore({
            key: "id",
            load: function () {
                return stateService.GetAllItems().toPromise().catch(err => { throw err.error });;
            },
            insert: (values: StateModel) => {
                return stateService.InsertItem(values).toPromise().catch(err => { throw err.error });
            },
            update: (key: string, values: any) => {
                var item = new UpdateItemModel();
                item.id = key;
                item.values = JSON.stringify(values);

                return stateService.UpdateItem(item).toPromise().catch(err => { throw err.error });
            },
            remove: (key: string) => {
                return stateService.DeleteItem(key).toPromise().catch(err => { throw err.error });
            }
        });

        stateService.GetCSVMappingTemplate().subscribe(m => {
            this.csvMappingTemplate = m;
        });
    }

    onToolbarPreparing(e) {
        e.toolbarOptions.items.unshift({
            location: 'before',
            template: 'totalGroupCount'
        },
            {
                location: 'after',
                widget: 'dxButton',
                options: {
                    text: "Import From CSV",
                    onClick: this.showCSVImportPopUp
                }
            });
    }

    showCSVImportPopUp() {
        this.csvImportPopupVisible = true;
        alert(this.csvImportPopupVisible);
    }
}
```

2) **state.component.html**

```
<div>
    <dx-data-grid [dataSource]="statesDataSourse" height="600" keyExpr="id" showBorders="true" id="accounts" (onToolbarPreparing)="onToolbarPreparing($event)">


        <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
        <dxo-scrolling mode="virtual"></dxo-scrolling>
        <dxo-editing mode="popup" [allowAdding]="true" [allowUpdating]="true" [allowDeleting]="true">
        </dxo-editing>


        <dxi-column dataField="code" caption="Code">
            <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Code is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
            <dxi-validation-rule type="stringLength" [max]="50" message="Max length is 50"></dxi-validation-rule>
        </dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Name">
            <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Name is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
            <dxi-validation-rule type="stringLength" [max]="250" message="Max length is 250"></dxi-validation-rule>
        </dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="alternativeCode" caption="Alternative Code">
            <dxi-validation-rule type="stringLength" [max]="50" message="Max length is 50"></dxi-validation-rule>
        </dxi-column>

    </dx-data-grid>
</div>
<div>
    <dx-popup class="popup" [showTitle]="true" title="Import From CSV" [dragEnabled]="false" [width]="300" [height]="250" [closeOnOutsideClick]="true"
        [(visible)]="csvImportPopupVisible">
        <b>this is popup</b>
    </dx-popup>
</div>

<div>{{csvImportPopupVisible}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это так сказать стандартная проблема видимости.

Внутри функции `showCSVImportPopUp()`, при вызове через `onClick: this.showCSVImportPopUp` `this` будет не тем, что вы ожидали, он будет вашим компонентом `dx-data-grid`.
Что бы эта конструкция заработала, нужно использовать функции `call` или `bind`.
Например так

```
onClick: this.showCSVImportPopUp.bind(this);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло мне!

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
showCSVImportPopUp() {
```

на

```
showCSVImportPopUp = () => {
```